# How do I block or painting a specific line in the table based on the value line numbers - Angolr 2 and NgFor

Tags: angular, html-table, row, block, ngfor

I work with angular2 .
In my case have a table of games, and in database have list of games that clicked before (one button - line can click once time).
So I want add class (block or paint it's never mind) to the number row that show in list of games.

```
<table id="table-list" class="table table-hover table-striped" >
<thead>
<tr class="strong" style="text-align: center">
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Host</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Guest</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
<tr *ngFor="#g of games | reverse ">
           <td> {{g.id}}</td>
           <td id="btn1"> <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,1)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">  {{g.host}}</button></td>
           <td id="btn2" > <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,'X')"type="button" class="btn btn-default">  X </button></td>
           <td  id="btn3" > <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,2)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">  {{g.guest}}</button></td>
</tbody>
```

css (block and paint):

```
.vis_button{
background-color:gray;
opacity: .7;
pointer-events: none;}
```

ts code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     firebase.database().ref('/usersFacebook/').child(fix_userEmail).child('GamesVotes').on('child_added', (snapshot)=> {
        this.gamesVoted.push(snapshot.val())
    })
}
```

this.gamesVoted --->> Is array of number id that user voted/click before that I want block/paint each row that show in this array in the table by id.
I try add class to row but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's a mistake in your `*ngFor` directive. I don't know which version of Angular 2 you are using, but you should use keyword `let` instead of `#` to define template variable. What you are looking for `ngClass` directive - it adds or removes style based on condition. In your case, it should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let g of games | reverse" [ngClass]="{ 'vis_button': gamesVoted.includes(g.id) }">
       <td> {{g.id}}</td>:
       <td id="btn1"> <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,1)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">  {{g.host}}</button></td>
       <td id="btn2" > <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,'X')"type="button" class="btn btn-default">  X </button></td>
       <td  id="btn3" > <button (click)="fbPostVote(g.id,2)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">  {{g.guest}}</button></td>
    </tr> //you are missing this line
</tbody>
```

`ngClass` directive checks if id of the game that is displayed in current row (`g.id`) is part of `gamesVoted` array and if it is, it adds `.vis_button` css class to that row.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.
I'll try it, hoping that will work.
And by the way, I do not know exactly what version I use, but 'let' not working, only # and because this I have no way to use the index of ngFor because it works with 'let i = index'

Comment: @Idan You should update to latest version of Angular 2... Anyway, let me know what you have achieved. By the way, you shouldn't mark answers as accepted until you check if provided solution really works for you.

Comment: Its work! thank you, you know how can i update version?